# Error in Groovy script: The current scope already contains a variable

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to write a groovy method for Jenkins pipeline. The method gets two variables, put them inside a string, and execute the string as a shell command.

Here is the method:

```
def method(A, B) {
        test = "cp app/scripts/" + A + "config." + B + "js app/scripts/config.js"

        def rc = sh(script: test, returnStatus: true)
        if (rc != 0) {
            error "Failed, exiting now..."
        }
}
```

Here is the error i get when i execute this code:

```
The current scope already contains a variable of the name rc
 @ line 148, column 13.
           def rc = sh(script: """
               ^
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: try using a different variable name than `rc`. This looks like a groovyC error to me...it is complaining that `rc` exists in scope already

Comment: I'd rather expect, that there is a `rc` from jenkins than suspecting the groovy compiler.

Comment: Thanks guys. I used other name than `rc` and it works.

Comment: @cfrick I meant from jenkins. I've seen this during groovyC especially with ast transforms. I wasn't suggesting a bug in groovyC :)

Comment: It's strictly recommended to give a more significant name to variables